# How to access Object Data Source Binding Value From Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have an old source code that uses the object data source to bind data to a Grid. I want to Store raw data sent by the object data source to a ViewState.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SelimYıldız - Still I am unable to figure out how to access data from the data source...

Comment: Do you want to assign the GridView DataSource to ViewState?

Comment: @Julián - Somehow I am able to achieve that. odsResult is my object data source. In a button click I call .Select() method to the odsResult and retrieve everything to the ViewState. It works. But I wonder is it the best way to do that?

Comment: You are storing a dataset in ViewState, I understand that ViewState works side by side with the client and sends the encrypted information, it means that the more information stores could affect the performance of the application. I have used ViewState to store small variables (string, int, etc.), but if I wanted to store a dataset you could use the "Session" object that works on the server side.

Comment: @Julián - I am using ViewState because it will not share among pages.